# AngularJS: reorder list after insert a new item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[This is my edited plunker from AngularJS' ordering example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/ggs4E5mJ8HDz3IRyrc7R?p=preview) The ordering is fine until my code for periodically updating the list of contacts adds a new person. The new person will not be re-sorted in the list, instead the user is always added to the bottom. I need the list to re-sort when a new user is added. Is there a way to do this?

This is essentially what I used to create new people, the rest of the ordering mechanisms from angular were left the same:

```
$scope.run_it = function() {
  setTimeout($scope.run_it, 3000);
  $scope.friends.push({name: 'New', phone: '000-0000', age: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)});
  $scope.$applyAsync();
};

setTimeout($scope.run_it, 3000);
```

Comment: Look into using $q and working with promises.

Comment: also angular has a special `$timeout` provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your order function does some weirdness with flipping the sort order, but overall all you need to do is watch the collection:

```
$scope.$watchCollection("friends", function () {
  $scope.order('age');
});
```

Comment: Covering my face in shame as I though I piped the list in `ng-repeat` to a `orderBy`. The behavior now makes sense as the list was only reordered on that function call.